# mongoDB getting 'undefined' by find

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, socket.io

I want to use all values that

```
bericht.find({
        room: room
      }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        str2 = str2 + docs.message;
```

This function can find, the only problem is I keep getting 'undefined'. But I want to use the value's and socket.emit the value's to the client size so all messages can be used there. Can anybody help me? How I can do this.

```js
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    var str2 = [];

    // Database Name
    const dbName = 'chatapplication';


    const findMessageFromRoom = function(room, db, callback) {
      // Get the messages from certain room
      const bericht = db.collection('Bericht');
      // Find some documents
      bericht.find({
        room: room
      }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        str2 = str2 + docs.message;
        // callback(docs);
      });
      console.log(str2);
      socket.emit('test1', str2);
    };

    function getAllMessagesInRoom(room) {
      MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Connected successfully to server");

        const db = client.db(dbName);

        findMessageFromRoom(room, db, function() {
          client.close();
        });

      });
    }

  )
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is asynchronous, it won't wait for the database query to finish, just logs the `str2` variable immediately. It's not defined at that time, so you get 'undefined' message on console.

**Use it like this:**

```
bericht.find({
    room: room
}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    str2 = str2 + docs.message;
    // callback(docs);

    console.log(str2);
    socket.emit('test1', str2);
});
```